# Database created from SQLite Browser not working in device "Android"

Tags: android

My proble is I created a device in sqlite database browser and its work fine in emulator.
but when a try my application to my device it cause force close.
and when I remove the database and create a new one using eclipse it works fine even in my device. But inserting a lot of data in database 1 by 1 realy freakin me out so anyone know a sqlite database browser that also work for device??!

Answer (score 1):

check out [this tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-have-default-database) for using database file in application.

Remember one thing that it only copy you DB file in application that's it.

Answer (score 0):

On real device you don't have permissions to sqlite database. That's why you won't be able to browse database like you can on a emulator.
See this for a work around.
[Tool to see android database, tables and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149438/tool-to-see-android-database-tables-and-data)

Comment: I can view database in my device if the database is not created outside or created using sqlite database browser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a pre-loaded DB outside of your app and use it in your app later, you will have to put it in your `assets` directory and then copy it to your apps storage space the first time your app is started.

This is due to the fact that as a security measure, on real (unrooted) devices nothing but your own app is allowed access to that apps databases directory (and certain other ones as well).

There is a good tutorial for creating/copying your own DB outside of the app and copying it to the apps databases directory [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

Comment: maybe that's the reason for my error because I only use push file to get the database from pc. tnx for the info